# Windows Error: How to get permissions to move, copy, delete files programatically in python

Tags: python, windows, posix

I have a django app where user uploads ZIP file and the app creates a repository of it, and stores it. During developing, I have created few ZIP files, repositories and doing the following operations

```
import shutil, tempfile

tmp = tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix='dj_app')
shutil.move(src_to_zip_dot_git_folder, tmp)
```

This code is raising `Windows Error: Access Denied [5]`. Well, on a Linux system its working well!

I guess, the program is unable to get necessary permissions to perform operations on these files. But how to fix them?

Answer (score 0):

This is typically out of scope of program itself and has to be managed by system administrator.

You shell ensure, that the user account, you are going to use for your app (Django?) has enough permissions to move the file, possibly adding permission to write to the target folder.

You can easily run into the same problem on Linux.

Comment: I've created app, created manually repos from same user account. also operating programmatically on same user account.

Comment: Then make sure, the file you are going to copy is already closed and no other process is using it. Also check, if you are not trying to overwrite existing file. If yo can, try making the same action out of Django, just from small test script.